# Spring boot hibernate/jpa batch update not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

**application property**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:as400://localhost/

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.batch_versioned_data = true
```

**Entity -**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity(name = "entity")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false);

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "HDR_ID", referencedColumnName = "HDR_ID")
   @JsonIgnore
   private Header header;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "STS_ID", referencedColumnName = "STS_ID")
   private Status status;
}
```

**Service -**

```
this.myRepository.saveAll(MyEntitylist);
```

Gradle -

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

I am using Spring boot 2.3.5.RELEASE.
I am trying to update bulk records using hibernate batch but it seems like it's not working. I am not getting any errors, Records are updating in DB without any problem but there is no performance improvement. Actually, I could not find any difference with or without Hibernate batch process. I checked with logs and their query is logging for every single record, for example, if I try to save 1000 records then there will be 1000 update queries in logs.

I am expecting fewer update queries after batch, depends on batch size and it should take comparatively less time than without batch queries.

Is there any configuration issue in my code?
Is there any option like reWriteBatchedInserts for jdbc:as400  to show a multi-row insert query?

Comment: Your post does not really say what the problem you are trying to solve is. Are you receiving an error?   It looks like you are missing the Id member in your MyEntity class.

Comment: Hi @crig, I have added more detail in the post. I am trying to improve performance using batch but it seems like it's not working and I am also not getting any error,

Answer (score 0):

Just because you see the queries in the database logs does not mean that batching does not work. JDBC batching is a protocol level optimization and is dependent on the driver support. A JDBC driver may implement this by issuing individual statements. The optimization usually comes from reusing the same server handle though and sending values in batches. The gain might be too small for 1000 elements though. You should consult your driver vendor about this if you do not see any improvements. You are not showing what kind of queries are logged though, are you sure that no other statements are executed in between the update statements?

Comment: Is there any way to check that batching is working or not?
I am using com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver

Comment: You can debug into `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch#addToBatch` to see if the JDBC batching API is used.

Comment: I have debugged the addToBatch method and it is working as expected, it is checking batchSize and if batchPosition == batchSize, it is excecuting the SQL query. Maybe I need to test with a large dataset to check perfornance and need to enable debug logs to add batch related logs in the log file  Thanks

Comment: I've found that batch updating does not really buy too much in the way of performance. At some level, you are still updating individual records which has to essentially be done one at a time. You save perhaps some of the back and forth if data can be sent over in bulk, but still each individual UPDATE stmt has to be run individually, in general. *I think.

Comment: If you can formulate this as a single DML update statement, that will always perform better obviously, but sometimes it's not possible or just easier to handle this way.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate disables insert batching at the JDBC level transparently if you use an identity identifier generator.

> https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/devguide/en-US/html_single/#batch